# Query won't save

Tags: php, mysql

I made this query to show me the 'rank' of the Result ordered by there points. The query works fine but for some reason, I did not get any results whent trying to fetch it with php
Maybe someone can tell me why?

```
(int) $a    = $_GET['a'];
if($ranking = $con->prepare("SET @rownum := 0; SELECT rank, id FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id FROM anime ORDER BY points DESC) as result WHERE id=$a"))
{
    $ranking->execute();
    $ranking->next_result();
    $ranking->bind_result($rank, $id);

    while($ranking->fetch()) 
    {
        var_dump($rank, $id);
        if($id == $a)
        {
          echo "<span class='rnknr'>#$rank</span>";
        }
    }

    $ranking->close();
}
```

}

Comment: Should that be mysql?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mysql and I saw a few code snippets like this

Comment: Well an update Query should look like this `UPDATE tablename SET column x = 'value1' WHERE id = 123`

Comment: But it's not to update... I only want to select the ranking number

Comment: It's returning the result of the first statement in the query, which is `SET @rownum := 0`.

Comment: after FROM must follow a tablename

Comment: I'm really confused right now... In phpmyadmin it works perfect and the output is 'ranking' with the ranking number and 'id' from the data but in php it does not return anything

Answer (score 0):

$ranking->execute(); may return multiple resultsets if query contains more than 1 expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(int) $a    = $_GET['a'];
if($ranking = $con->prepare("SET @rownum := 0; SELECT rank, id FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id FROM anime ORDER BY points DESC) as result WHERE id=1"))
{
    $ranking->execute();
    $ranking->next_result(); //<- advance to the result set for 2nd query (The select query)
    $ranking->bind_result($rank, $id);

    while($ranking->fetch()) 
    {
    if($id == $a)
        {
          echo "<span class='rnknr'>#$rank</span>";
        }
    }

    $ranking->close();
}
```

You have 2 queries in your statement so only calling fetch will give you the result of the first query `SET @rownum := 0`.  You need to advance to the 2nd result set by calling `next_result`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it out but it still won't work

Answer (score 0):

You must use some special method from [mysqli::multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) because this is multi query :) Now your code could look like this:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB);

#(int) $a = $_GET['a']; -> What is this ?

$a = (int)$_GET['a']; //This is simplest casting

$sql = 'SET @rownum := 0; SELECT rank, id FROM (SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id FROM anime ORDER BY points DESC) as result WHERE id='.$a;
if ($mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    $mysqli->next_result();
    $result = $mysqli->store_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($row['id'] == $a)
        {
          echo "rank: #{$row['rank']}";
        }
    }
}
```